# UIFontMetrics: scaled font size calculation

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, uifont, dynamic-type-feature

In iOS 11 `UIFontMetrics` class was introduced. I did some experimenting but I didn't understand how [scaledFont(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontmetrics/2877385-scaledfont) method calculates the font size of returned font. For example, Apple [says](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/) that for **Large (Default)** dynamic type size, **body** style size is **17 (points)** and for **AX5** (the most large) dynamic type size, **body** style size is **53**. So, in a device with **AX5** as type size, when I call

```
UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
```

I correctly obtain a font size of **53**. If I call

```
UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17))
```

I expect the same font size of **53**, but I obtain a font size of **48**.

Why? How does [scaledFont(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontmetrics/2877385-scaledfont) method calculate the font size of returned font?

==== EDIT ===

I tried to print the two fonts in **Large** and **AX5** dynamic type size. These are the results:

**Large**

```
let font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
let font1 = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17))
print(font)   
print(font1)

// Output
// <UICTFont: 0x7fd36a414b80> font-family: ".SFUIText"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt
// <UICTFont: 0x7fd36a416360> font-family: ".SFUIText"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt
```

**AX5**

```
let font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
let font1 = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17))
print(font)
print(font1) 

// Output
// <UICTFont: 0x7f8addf1baa0> font-family: ".SFUIDisplay"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 53.00pt
// <UICTFont: 0x7f8addf1eba0> font-family: ".SFUIDisplay"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 48.00pt
```

Answer (score 5):

I got the same conclusion as @Giorgio about the unlogical result of his example.

I made research and many tests about this topic to conclude that the `scaledFont(for:)` method :

- May be seen as a **black box** that contains a private algorithm to get the proper size and whose rationale behind  isn't clear... to me.
- **Doesn't scale custom fonts exactly like the system font** but is closer enough to use its reference table as a guide.
- **Must be used only with custom fonts** otherwise the results may differ from those defined in the Apple website if the system font is the incoming parameter.

Anytime you need the system font, use the `preferredFont(forTextStyle:)` method to be sure of the text-sized result otherwise `scaledFont(for:)` is your best friend.

There's no point size precision result with this method unless for the `.large` Dynamic Type size for which possible custom fonts may be accurately defined.

Once the content size category changes, **only an approximation for custom font can be predicted with the `scaledFont(for:)` method**.

To avoid possible collisions between text styles at a specific Dynamic Type size *(Caption size may become bigger than a Title for instance)*, the best way is to define the `.large` font sizes not too far from the Apple system font's... or to [compare graphically every text style](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/criteria-ios.html#colours).

Answer (score 0):

Likely since they are different fonts, and the pointSize 48 for the default system font is the same size as pointSize 53 of the body font.

Pointsize != actual rendered size.

(but I am just guessing, you will need to draw them side by side to make a comparison).

Comment: Thanks @Olof_t, why do you say that they are different fonts? It's system font in both cases.

Comment: The "system font" is actually different for body, header, etc. So when you ask for preferred font for body, you get one font, but the basic system font (with size 17) is another (most likely).

Comment: As I wrote in question, "Apple says that for Large (Default) dynamic type size, body style size is 17 (points)".

Comment: @Giorgio They are probably *different fonts*, "body" is one font and UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17) will give you another. Print them out and see. When scaled to Ax5 the systemFont will need to use a different point size to be the same optical size as the body-font. I cannot explain this any better - sorry.

Comment: No @Olof_t. They are the _same font_! I just tried and I edited my question with code and test results